# Модификация регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Добрый день подскажите как можно модифицировать регулярное выражение (Условния: текст. Латинские и кириллические буквы в т.ч. "ё", цифры, а также "пробел"  "-"  "."  "," "\".)

```
.matches(/^[a-zA-ZА-ЯЁа-яё`'\s-]+$/, 'Поле может содержать латиницу или кириллицу, пробелы, апострофы и дефисы')
```

Данное уравнение работает приемлемо, однако стоит ввести точку, и српазу ругается на неё. Подскажите как можно это побороть.

Comment: `/^[a-zA-ZА-ЯЁа-яё\`,\\'\s.-]+$/` - какие проблемы?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Большое спасибо, чег-то я это затупил :)
Добавьте пожалуйста развернутый ответ, что бы я пометил его как правильный, и вам была зачислена репутация.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете добавить те символы, которые вам нужны, в любое место в символьный класс, но только следите, чтобы `-` остался либо в начале, либо в конце, или экранируйте его (тогда будет всё равно, где он находится).

```
/^[a-zA-ZА-ЯЁа-яё`,\\'\s.-]+$/
```

Обратите внимание, `\` необходимо экранировать всегда.

В общем случае, если нужно добавить `-`, `]`, `\` или `^` в символьный класс, экранируйте их.